# How to ask or claim or talk to a moderator?

Tags: feature-request

I just want know if there is some way to talk or to claim something to a moderator/moderators if there is something I am not satisfied with. For example, a special room for moderators, an mailing system, a ask-a-moderator button or something like that?

This is just to enable communications between users for they which will be satisfied and will know the usability of the site and solve their problems.

Actually, I have someone who voted me up and I got the voting up reversed, and I don't know if it's a Stack Exchange spider, or not, and if it's a Stack Exchange spider, why is it considered as reverse voting up again?

It feels like a spider, because I got nine upvotes in one minute. So why then is it considered as serial upvoting from the system itself if it's the system who is doing this spidering?

I wish I'm not wrong :)

Comment: maybe you already found the way how to do ...

Comment: Someone clearly serially upvoted you 2 days ago and that was reversed. That's an automatic process. As for contacting moderators, you can flag, or you can simply ask a question here (though regular users can respond as well).

Comment: @Bart How can you know *anything* "clearly" from reading this question? What the heck is a "stack spider"?

Comment: 32 posts upvoted in 4 minutes... now that's dedication.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer please consider it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i have added An edit , its 9 upvotes in one minute

Comment: I think you need to clarify what a spider is because there are at least 2 of us looking at this question now who don't know what you mean

Comment: spider i mean some program or bot or function which used to do this from time to time to upvote users.

Comment: There is no such script/bot in the SE system that automatically upvotes people.  It is all done by the community.  Someone who is a "fan" of yours upvoted 32 posts in a 4 minute span and it was reversed the next day

Comment: @CodyGray Because I am that awesome. That's why. ;)

Comment: I figured it must be your *spidey* sense.

Comment: you guys are 3 talking here and i got 2 downvotes did someone have missed to downvote ? . when someone asks a question it will be serial downvoting and wich it will be reversed tomorrow :) .

Comment: @user998158: serial downvoting is downvoting on a bunch of posts by the same person, not on one post by a lot of people.

Comment: @user998158 just because Cody, Bart, and I (and now Wooble) are the only people commenting, you have no idea who downvoted this post.  This post has been viewed 29 times so any one of them could have downvoted you.

Comment: related to @psubsee2003´s comment above, I voted and I haven't commented. (oops)

Comment: The elusive moderator! He comments! And downvotes!

Answer (score 7):

The serial upvoting has been an action of a user. It was not the system (i.e. SO/SE) which performed the upvoting. Whether or not the user did that manually or automatically is not really important.

What is important however is that this is considered fraudulent voting behaviour. And [there are systems in place which will reverse it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). As far as automatic processes go, that one is indeed automatic.